# How to apply pinch zoom on stickerView/ClipArt/ custom view android

Tags: android, android-layout, pinchzoom

How to apply pinch zoom on **`stickerView`** or **`ClipArt`** or **`custom view`** android. I tried this [**demo**](http://ravikoradiya.com/android/StickerDemo/StickerDemo.zip).
but not succeeded sometimes it will disappear view some time view become stuck, it worked fine when i want to zoom-in zoom-out from button but not on multi-touch.

**screenshot:**

[image]

**Java**

```
public class ClipArt extends RelativeLayout {
    int baseh;
    int basew;
    int basex;
    int basey;
    ImageButton btndel;
    ImageButton btnrot;
    ImageButton btnscl;
    RelativeLayout clip;
    Context cntx;
    boolean freeze = false;
    int h;
    int i;
    ImageView image;
    String imageUri;
    boolean isShadow;
    int iv;
    RelativeLayout layBg;
    RelativeLayout layGroup;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    public LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int margl;
    int margt;
    float opacity = 1.0F;
    Bitmap originalBitmap;
    int pivx;
    int pivy;
    int pos;
    Bitmap shadowBitmap;
    float startDegree;
    String[] v;

    public ClipArt(Context paramContext) {
        super(paramContext);
        cntx = paramContext;
        layGroup = this;

        basex = 0;
        basey = 0;
        pivx = 0;
        pivy = 0;

        mInflater = ((LayoutInflater) paramContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater"));
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.clipart, this, true);
        btndel = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.del));
        btnrot = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rotate));
        btnscl = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sacle));

        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);
        layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        image = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clipart));
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ClipArt.this.cntx,
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent paramAnonymous2MotionEvent) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        layGroup.invalidate();
                        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                        layGroup.performClick();
                        basex = ((int) (event.getRawX() - layoutParams.leftMargin));
                        basey = ((int) (event.getRawY() - layoutParams.topMargin));
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int i = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int j = (int) event.getRawY();
                        layBg = ((RelativeLayout) getParent());
                        if ((i - basex > -(layGroup.getWidth() * 2 / 3))
                                && (i - basex < layBg.getWidth() - layGroup.getWidth() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = (i - basex);
                        }
                        if ((j - basey > -(layGroup.getHeight() * 2 / 3))
                                && (j - basey < layBg.getHeight() - layGroup.getHeight() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = (j - basey);
                        }
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -1000;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -1000;
                        layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        this.btnscl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    int j = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int i = (int) event.getRawY();
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layGroup.getLayoutParams();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.invalidate();
                        ClipArt.this.basex = j;
                        ClipArt.this.basey = i;
                        ClipArt.this.basew = ClipArt.this.layGroup.getWidth();
                        ClipArt.this.baseh = ClipArt.this.layGroup.getHeight();
                        int[] loaction = new int[2];
                        layGroup.getLocationOnScreen(loaction);
                        margl = layoutParams.leftMargin;
                        margt = layoutParams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        float f2 = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(i - ClipArt.this.basey, j - ClipArt.this.basex));
                        float f1 = f2;
                        if (f2 < 0.0F) {
                            f1 = f2 + 360.0F;
                        }
                        j -= ClipArt.this.basex;
                        int k = i - ClipArt.this.basey;
                        i = (int) (Math.sqrt(j * j + k * k)
                                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(f1 - ClipArt.this.layGroup.getRotation())));
                        j = (int) (Math.sqrt(i * i + k * k)
                                * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(f1 - ClipArt.this.layGroup.getRotation())));
                        k = i * 2 + ClipArt.this.basew;
                        int m = j * 2 + ClipArt.this.baseh;
                        if (k > 150) {
                            layoutParams.width = k;
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = (ClipArt.this.margl - i);
                        }
                        if (m > 150) {
                            layoutParams.height = m;
                            layoutParams.topMargin = (ClipArt.this.margt - j);
                        }
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.performLongClick();
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
                return ClipArt.this.freeze;
            }
        });
        this.btnrot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ClipArt.this.layGroup.getLayoutParams();
                    ClipArt.this.layBg = ((RelativeLayout) ClipArt.this.getParent());
                    int[] arrayOfInt = new int[2];
                    layBg.getLocationOnScreen(arrayOfInt);
                    int i = (int) event.getRawX() - arrayOfInt[0];
                    int j = (int) event.getRawY() - arrayOfInt[1];
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.invalidate();
                        ClipArt.this.startDegree = layGroup.getRotation();
                        ClipArt.this.pivx = (layoutParams.leftMargin + ClipArt.this.getWidth() / 2);
                        ClipArt.this.pivy = (layoutParams.topMargin + ClipArt.this.getHeight() / 2);
                        ClipArt.this.basex = (i - ClipArt.this.pivx);
                        ClipArt.this.basey = (ClipArt.this.pivy - j);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int k = ClipArt.this.pivx;
                        int m = ClipArt.this.pivy;
                        j = (int) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ClipArt.this.basey, ClipArt.this.basex))
                                - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m - j, i - k)));
                        i = j;
                        if (j < 0) {
                            i = j + 360;
                        }
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.setRotation((ClipArt.this.startDegree + i) % 360.0F);
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return ClipArt.this.freeze;
            }
        });
        this.btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    layBg = ((RelativeLayout) ClipArt.this.getParent());
                    layBg.performClick();
                    layBg.removeView(ClipArt.this.layGroup);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void disableAll() {
        this.btndel.setVisibility(4);
        this.btnrot.setVisibility(4);
        this.btnscl.setVisibility(4);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setFreeze(boolean paramBoolean) {
        this.freeze = paramBoolean;
    }
}
```

**Layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rotate" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/rotation"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/sacle" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/pointer"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/del" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/close"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/clipart" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where you got this demo.? can you please mention project's  link into comment?